# using General game engines on Android, is it possible?

Tags: android, graphics, game-engine

Game engines like Quack, OGRE3D, JMonkeyEngine and Blender are used for PC games but how hard is to use it for Android games?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - this site is more appropriate to ask this question.

Comment: Also, you question is very subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular game engines are designed for the Windows architecture, both hardware specification and the OS running the game.

Android is completely different as it's mostly used on smartphones / tablets, meaning lower hardware, and the OS is based on Linux. For a game engine to enable export to Android (Unity3D does it for example), it needs to be rewritten according to the os/hardware specifications.